# Longest known polynomial progression of distinct primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is Euler’s quadratic progression of forty distinct primes (the values of $n^2-n+41$ for $n$ between 1 and 40) still the longest known sequence of this kind?

I’d also be curious to know the longest known degree-1 (aka arithmetic) and degree-3 polynomial progressions of distinct primes; I suspect they are much shorter.

Comment: Does http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html not answer this question?

Comment: Yes it does answer my question (at least as regards polynomial progressions of degree > 1); thanks! My suspicion about Euler's polynomial being the reigning champion turned out to be incorrect; longer progressions are known. As for the degree 1 case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression reports that as of last year the longest known arithmetic progression of primes has length 26.